# ASP.NET Web Development Server

Tags: asp.net, iis, webserver

Can someone explain how the ASP.NET Web Development Server work? I don't have IIS installed on my development machine. So Visual Studio 2008 is debugging my web app project in the built-in web server. I want to know where do all the files get deployed to for debugging. Is there any folder similar to \inetput\wwwroot? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The web server is an executable file named **WebDev.WebServer.EXE** and located in \WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727. When debugging the web site, Visual Studio starts up an instance of the application with the following parameters.

*WebDev.WebServer.exe \port \path [\vpath]*

This ASP.NET Development Server simply uses the compiled web application in the debug folder, which is provided as /path, to serve the website.

You can read more about this [here](http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Using-VS/Using-the-Visual-Studio-Builtin-Web-Server-from-the-Command-Line/).

Answer (score 2):

Do a search for a folder called "Temporary ASP.NET Files". This is where files are precompiled and temporarily deployed/stored for the development server (Cassini) to serve them up.

On my machine, the directory is C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files, and it is currently over 260MB.

Answer (score 1):

It uses your /bin dir for the assembly and your aspx files for the aspx files. The files aren't really deployed, they are just assembled/compiled and then the local web server uses them.

Answer (score 1):

The files don't get deployed at all. The Web Development Server (often called Cassini) binds directly to the website or web application folder.

Comment: How do you figure?  The files have to get precompiled somewhere!